# why does it happen that a process runs with high memory usage and low CPU usage

Tags: linux, memory, process, operating-system, cpu-usage

I'm running a python program on a linux system, the program is for computing a network with millions of nodes.

The linux system has 16 G memory. After running some time, I notice that the program(or process) occupies 95%(or above) of the memory, but only 1 or 0% of the CPU. I'm wondering on what conditions the system behaves like this(not specific to the above case)?

BTW, I killed the process and notice the process is printing a set with millions of tuples to a file because I notice there are already around 2 million tuples has been printed to the outfile(around 1.5 million is remaining)

```
  for pair in mapped_pairs:
    a=pair[0]
    b=pair[1]
    print('%d %d'%(a,b), file=outfile)

  outfile.close()
```

so this means the printing occupies a lot of memory?

Comment: First make sure that:
1-The cache is not calculated as used.
2-There is no memory leaks in your app.

Comment: I'm runnign a python script and there should not be memory leaks. what do you meant that "The cache is not calculated as used."?

Comment: If you are using "free -m" for example, consider the values from this line: -/+ buffers/cache